# How to use substring when working with a StringMatrix or CharacterMatrix object in rcpp?

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

When using rcpp, I am attempting to use substring on a CharacterMatrix or StringMatrix object, as shown below:

```
test <- cxxfunction(signature(), plugin = "Rcpp", body = '
+                     Rcpp::CharacterMatrix v(1,1);
+                     v(0,0) = "Hello";
+                     v(0,0) = v(0,0).substr(0,4);
+                     return v;')
```

But when I run this, I get the error:

```
Error in compileCode(f, code, language = language, verbose = verbose) : 
  Compilation ERROR, function(s)/method(s) not created! file80c3f1e86e5.cpp:33:37: error: no member named 'substr' in 'Rcpp::internal::string_proxy<16>'
                    v(0,0) = v(0,0).substr(0,4);
                             ~~~~~~ ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [file80c3f1e86e5.o] Error 1
In addition: Warning message:
running command '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R CMD SHLIB file80c3f1e86e5.cpp 2> file80c3f1e86e5.cpp.err.txt' had status 1
```

How can I use substring on a certain element in a CharacterMatrix? Is there an alternative to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to @nrussell's answer but a bit more explicit -- first create a `string`, then use `substr()` on it.

#### Code

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::string getsubstr(CharacterMatrix M) {
  std::string s = as<std::string>(M(0,0));
  return s.substr(0,4);
}

/*** R
getsubstr(matrix(c("Hello", "world", "brown", "fox"), 2, 2))
*/
```

#### Running it

```
R> sourceCpp("/tmp/charmat.cpp")

R> getsubstr(matrix(c("Hello", "world", "brown", "fox"), 2, 2))
[1] "Hell"
R>
```